# Do you prove all theorems whilst studying?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, education, self-learning, learning

When you come across a new theorem, do you always try to prove it first before reading the proof within the text? I'm a CS undergrad with a bit of an interest in maths. I've not gone very far in my studies -- sequence two of Calculus -- but what I'm trying to understand right now, though, is how one actually goes about studying so that when finished with a good text, there's more of an intuitive understanding than superficial.

After reading "The Art Of Problem Solving" from the Final Perspectives section of part eight in 'The Princeton Companion to Mathematics', it seems to hint at approaching studying in that very way. A quote in particular, from  Eisenstein, that caught my attention was the following -- I'm not going to paraphrase much:

> The method used by the director was as follows: each student had to
>   prove the theorems consecutively. No lecture took place at all. No one
>   was allowed to tell his solutions to anybody else and each student
>   received the next theorem to prove, independent of the other students,
>   as soon as he had proved the preceding one correctly, and as long as
>   he had understood the reasoning. This was a completely new activity
>   for me, and one which I grasped with incredible enthusiasm and an
>   eagerness for knowledge. Already, with the first theorem, I was far
>   ahead of the others, and while my peers were still struggling with the
>   eleventh or twelfth, I had already proved the hundredth. There was
>   only one young fellow, now a medicine student, who could come close to
>   me. While this method is very good, strengthening, as it does, the
>   powers of deduction and encouraging autonomous thinking and
>   competition among students, generally speaking, it can probably not be
>   adapted. For as much as I can see its advantages, one must admit that
>   it isolates a certain strength, and one does not obtain an overview of
>   the whole subject, which can only be achieved by a good lecture. Once
>   one has acquired a great variety of material through [...] For
>   students, this method is practicable only if it deals with small
>   fields of easily, understandable knowledge, especially geometric
>   theorems, which do not require new insights and ideas.

I feel that this type of environment is something you don't often see, especially in the US -- perhaps that's why so many of our greats are foreign born. As I understand it, he does go on to say that he wouldn't particularly recommend that method of study for higher mathematics, though.

A similar question was posed to mathoverflow where Tim Gowers (Fields Medal) went on to say that he recommended similar methods to study: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3951/memorizing-theorems)

I'm not quite certain that I understood the context of it all, though. Upon asking a few people whose opinion mattered to me, I was told that it if time were precious to me, it would be a waste going about studying mathematics in that way, so I'd like to get some perspective from you math.stackexchange. How do you go about studying your texts?

Edit: Broken link added fixed.

Comment: There are two kinds of mathematicians: those who do *not* try to prove all theorems before reading the proofs and liars.

Comment: I tried to. But I don't have that kind time.

Comment: The Real Analysis classes I took years (decades!) ago at Bowdoin College were lecture-less. The professor (William Barker) divided us into small groups and gave us (hand-written!) handouts and problem sets that guided us through proving *everything* in the course. Naturally, this approach took longer than normal --we had extra-long and extra-many class periods to attend-- but, doggonit, we built Calculus with our own hands! Very satisfying.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Would it be ideal to prove the theorem after examining the proof in detail? What I'm really trying to understand here is what is the proper way to study mathematics to gain an intuitive feel.

Comment: @DayLateDon It sounds like the class surely would have been rewarding. I'm working through Spivak's 'Calculus' right now and I'm wanting to try that approach, but I don't know how practical that would actually be. What I'm really searching for is the proper way to study mathematics.

Comment: Crossposted to Reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/qoocl/ . The broken link to the MathOverflow question is [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3951/memorizing-theorems).

Comment: As far as studying, I don't think you should ever try to learn mathematics linearly.  As a prof of mine once remarked, it's written linearly to be easily checked for correctness, not to be understood.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happened once or twice a teacher showed us a theorem that he admitted "I would find that hard to proove my self/ the proof for that is really too long". If it is barely at the reach of a teacher I doubt a student can handle it (not impossible though).

Comment: @Blue Really cool class. However i found a topology book with same spirit. It's called "Elementary Topology : Problem Textbook" by Viro, Ivanov, Netsvrtaev and Kharlamov.

Comment: Miles Stevenson, is this [quora user](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-need-to-prove-most-of-the-theorems-in-math-textbooks-when-learning-Read-the-details) you?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There is a continuum in the way one understands a theorem.
At one end  of the spectrum mathematicians  just try to understand the statement and use it as a black box .
At the other end they understand the theorem so well that they improve on it: this is called research.

An important thing to keep in mind is that your attitude toward a result is not fixed for ever: you may first consider  it as a black box and solve exercises by blindly using it, then see how it is quoted in proving corollaries or other theorems and finally come back to it and realize that it is actually quite natural.

Professors  have  the advantage that they really have to understand a theorem if they want to teach it well and answer the students' questions.
One of the great aspects of this site is that everybody can be a teacher: 
 I strongly advise you to try and answer questions here.  They are at all possible levels and I am sure you can find some that you will  answer very competently.

A paradoxical way of expressing what it means to have understood a theorem is to say that ideally you have to reach the stage where you consider that all its proofs in the literature are "wrong": it is a patently absurd statement but it conveys the idea that the theorem is now yours because you have integrated it into your own mathematical world.

**Edit**
Since Neal asks about this in his comment, let me emphasize that when I say that proofs in the literature are "wrong" I mean that, although they are technically 100% correct, they don't correspond to the subjective way one has organized one's understanding of the subject.

For example, the definition I like for a finite  field extension $K/k$ to be separable is that it is étale i.e. that the tensor product with an algebraic closure of $k$ is split: $K\otimes_k\bar k\cong \overline {k} ^n$ .
I know this is rather idiosyncratic and of course I know the equivalence with the usual definition, but then I feel that long proofs that $\mathbb C\otimes _\mathbb R\mathbb C$ is not a field are "wrong" since I know,  by the  definition of separable  I have interiorized, that  $\mathbb C\otimes _\mathbb R\mathbb C=\mathbb C^2$.
Let me emphasize  that all this a completely personal and secret [till today :-)] attitude within myself and that I absolutely don't advocate that other mathematicians should change their definition of separable.

Comment: Another big +1.  As a student of mathematics, it is important to realize (i) there are many different levels of understanding.  If you try to ignore this you will either get weighed down on very basic stuff and never move out of that small domain or (worse) will not have a deep understanding of *anything*; and (ii) the level of one's understanding of any given part of mathematics is a function of time...which is not even guaranteed to be non-decreasing, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: Thanks, @Pete: it feels great for me to to know that we hold similar views on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

I did try to prove propositions in my textbooks before reading proofs when I was studying subjects like linear algebra, real analysis... But later on when things becoming more and more difficult, I had to give it up, and today I am still wondering if that was worthwhile...Because on one hand, there are many benefits of doing so: you may gain better understanding of the statement, improve you skill of proving things (), and you get great joy when you work something out! On the other hand, you will process very slowly (if not then congratulation!), but there is tons more to explore.

However, I do have some little suggestions:

1. if you develop the hobby of proving everything on you own, do not forget to zoom out from your proof of a specific statement and review the big picture of a lecture, a section or even a subject once for a while.
2. if you don't want to prove it, read others' proof, don't skip it.
3. maybe you can pick one or two subjects which are most important or interesting for you.

Answer (score 3):

See my question on mathoverflow for books that are designed for this sort of study:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12709/are-there-any-books-that-take-a-theorems-as-problems-approach

Also, from a short bio of S.Ramanujan:

> At sixteen, Ramanujan borrowed the English text "Synopsis of Pure Mathematics". This work was to prove a deep influence on Ramanujan's development as a mathematician, for it offered mathematical theorems without accompanying proofs, thereby prompting Ramanujan to prove the material by his own mathematical cunning.

Full text here: http://myhero.com/go/hero.asp?hero=s_ramanujan

Comment: Regarding Ramanujan and *Carr's Synopsis*, while it is an inspiring story, one should bear in mind how exceptional Ramanujan was as a mathematician.  (I think that most would agree that this was *not* caused by his learning from *Carr's Synopsis*, but rather that his ability to extract what he did from *Carr's Synopsis* was a sign of his remarkable nature). Regards,