# What is the tensor product $M_n(L)\otimes_K L$, where $L/K$ is a quadratic extension?

Tags: commutative-algebra

What is the tensor product $M_n(L)\otimes_K L$, where $L/K$ is a quadratic extension?

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $L/K$ a quadratic extension.
Let $\rho\in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ denote the nontrivial element of the Galois group.
Let $M_n(L)$ denote the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices over $L$.
The "conjugation" $\rho$ acts on $M_n(L)$ by conjugating each matrix element.

I want to understand the tensor product $M_n(L)\otimes_K L$
as an algebra over the right-hand $L$,
with conjugation coming from the action of $\rho$ on $M_n(L)$.
Of course it must be $M_n(L)\oplus M_n(L)$ (and the conjugation  must send $(X,Y)\in M_n(L)\oplus M_n(L)$ to $(Y^\rho,X^\rho)$).
Why is it so, and how can I construct an explicit isomorphism of $L$-algebras  $M_n(L)\otimes_K L\to M_n(L)\oplus M_n(L)$
(in light of the answers to my previous question [Tensor product algebra $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181788))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take the $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$-equivariant isomorphism of $L$-algebras given by   $$M_n(L)\otimes_K L\xrightarrow {\cong } M_n(L)\times  M_n(L):A\otimes l\mapsto (A\cdot l,A^\rho\cdot l)          $$