# Is a Lie algebra a complex or a real vector space?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to learn Lie theory and for this purpose I worked out the Lie algebras of some matrix groups. The examples I worked happened to be complex matrix groups and it lead me to wonder whether, when I try to determine a basis, I had to find a complex or a real basis.

> Is there any convention, definition or otherwise a way to know whether
>   a Lie algebra is to be understood as a complex or real vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A real Lie algebra is a real vector space and a complex Lie algebra is a complex vector space. Standard notations for standard Lie algebras usually implicitly specify which is which; for example, $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is naturally a real Lie algebra while $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is naturally a complex Lie algebra. If the author does not specify then you need to figure out which is intended from context.

Two warnings: $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is a real Lie algebra. It does not have a natural complex structure. And people frequently take complexifications $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ of real Lie algebras, e.g. when determining their complex representation theory.

Comment: If it's not specified but the Lie groups are complex, like $SL_n(\mathbb C)$, should I assume that the Lie algebras are taken to be complex? (I was showing that two Lie algebras are isomorphic and it might not matter for this purpose...?)

Comment: @learner: probably, but keep in mind that $U(n)$, for example, is not a complex Lie group.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about this notation "$⊗_ℝ ℂ$ "? Is this a tensor product $⊗$ and ℝ is for the ring or for the real number? (I find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181788/tensor-product-algebra-mathbbc-otimes-mathbbr-mathbbc)

Comment: Another question: () is a real Lie group. But () matrix representation is usually written in G$_$(ℂ) which seems generally a complex Lie group. So how do I digest the difference between () vs G$_$(ℂ)?

Comment: Many thanks!!! voted 1

Comment: Could you comment?

Answer (score 2):

In general a Lie algebra is defined over an *arbitrary* field. For connection with $p$-groups, the field may be also a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of characteristic $p>0$. Many results for Lie algebras, however, are only true over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, e.g., Lie's theorem for Lie algebras. Note that the classification of finite-dimensional simple Lie algebras in characteristic $p>0$ differs drastically from the one in characteristic $0$.

Comment: Another question: () is a real Lie group. But () matrix representation is usually written in G(ℂ) which seems generally a complex Lie group. So how do I digest the difference between () vs G(ℂ)? real Lie group vs complex Lie group?

Comment: Many thanks!!! voted 1