# External tensor product of indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ (maybe characteristic is not important here, but certainly algebraic closure is).  Let $A$ and $B$ denote finite-dimensional associative algebras over $k$.  Let $M$ be an indecomposable $A$-module and $N$ an indecomposable $B$-module (both $M$ and $N$ finite-dimensional, of course).

Then is the external tensor product module $M\boxtimes_k N$ indecomposable over $A\otimes_k B$?

Comment: [This seems to be a counterexample.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312977/when-is-the-external-tensor-product-of-indecomposable-modules-indecomposable)

Comment: Hi Kyle!! How are you :)  so in that they don't assume algebraically closed.  (But this is the sort of question I would want to ask you)