# Atiyah Macdonald- Commutative algebra Chapter 2 Question 13

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

This question is from the book **Atiyah Macdonald- Commutative algebra.**

[image]

Firstly I know that $g$ is an $A$-module homomorphism and $p$ is both an $A$-module and $B$-module homomorphism. Also $pg = id_N$. Now for any $b \otimes_A n \in N_B$,

$gp(b \otimes_A n) - b \otimes_A n$ $\in Ker(p) $

So, $b \otimes_A n = (gp(b \otimes_A n)-b \otimes_A n)+(b \otimes_A n+b \otimes_A n-gp(b \otimes_A n))$

So, I am left to show that $b \otimes_A n \in Im(g)$.

$b \otimes_A n = b(1 \otimes_A n)$   [ since  $N_B$  is a $B$-module]     $= b g(n) $

But I cannot show this is equal to $g(bn)$. How do I proceed?

Comment: I'm trying to break $b \otimes n$ into two terms.One of them is in ker p so I'm trying to show the other is in Im g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that [$g$ may not be an $B$-module homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3339152/677368).

Instead of trying to show $bg(n)=g(bn)$, you could use your result $p \circ g =id_N$.

Let $b \otimes_A n \in N_B$ be given. Then $p(b \otimes_A n)=bn=(p \circ g)(bn)=p(1 \otimes_A bn)$

Thus $$b \otimes_A n = (b \otimes_A n - 1 \otimes_A bn) + 1 \otimes_A bn  $$
where $ (b \otimes_A n - 1 \otimes_A bn) \in \ker(p)$ and $1 \otimes_A bn = g(bn) \in \text{im}(g)$.

Comment: How is $g(bn)$ well defined? We are considering the domain of $g$ to be $N$ as an $A$-module, and $bn$ only belongs to $N$ when seen as a $B$-module.

Comment: @ImHackingXD Before being a homomorphism, $g$ is first a **funcion** from the **set** $N$ to $N_B$. It is then proved to be a homomorphism. The expression $bn$ denotes some element of $N$ and thus $g(bn)$ is well-defined; there is no confusion on this issue.