# Reduceness and faithfully flatness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a "well known question" for which I do not find a reference.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be a commutative rings and $A\rightarrow B$ be a faithfully flat morphism. Let $C$ be a ring over $A$. Is it true that $$C_{red}\otimes B\cong (C\otimes B)_{red}?$$ 
>   In other words does faithful flatness commute with taking the reduced structure?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your notation. First, I assume you mean $C$ is a module over $A$. By $C_{red}$ do you mean $C$ as a module over the reduced ring $A_{red}?$

Comment: I think he means $C$ is an $A$-algebra and $C_{red}$ is $C/\operatorname{Nil}(C)$ as an $A$-algebra.

Comment: There is no reason for $C_{red}\otimes B$ to be reduced, so the isomorphism does not hold in general.

Answer (score 3):

[It's not hard to find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308015/how-to-show-the-tensor-product-of-reduced-k-algebra-must-be-reduced) a field extension $k\subset K$ such that $K\otimes_kK$ is not reduced.