# Generators for (radical) ideal of product of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $X\subset \mathbb{A}^N$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{A}^M$ are affine varieties with $X=Z(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ and $Y=Z(g_1,\dots,g_m)$ then $X\times Y\subset\mathbb{A}^{N+M}$ is an affine variety with $X\times Y=Z(f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_m)$.  But if we take $f_1,\dots,f_n$ and $g_1,\dots,g_m$ to generate the ideal of $X$ and $Y$ respectively then must $f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_n$ generate the ideal of $X\times Y$?

This is equivalent to asking if given $f_1,\dots,f_n\in\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $g_1,\dots,g_n\in\mathbb{k}[y_1,\dots,y_m]$ generating radical ideals whether $f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_n\in\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]$ generate a radical ideal.

This is true, for example, if the ideals are monomial ideals.  But in general I don't really have good intuition for this and the main reason I am asking is because it would make working with product varieties a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then for two $k$-algebras $A$ and $B$ which
are also integral domains, we will have $A\otimes_kB$ is an integral
domain. ([Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300917/tensor-product-of-domains-is-a-domain).)

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\},Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$.
Now suppose $I,J$ are radical ideals in $k[X]$ and $k[Y]$
respectively, and suppose $k$ is algebraically closed. We will prove that $(I,J)$ is a radical ideal in
$k[X,Y]$.

There are finitely many prime ideals
$\mathfrak{p}_i\subseteq k[X]$, $\mathfrak{q}_j\subseteq k[Y]$ respectively such that $I=\cap_i
\mathfrak{p}_i$ and $J=\cap_j \mathfrak{q}_j$. Thus we have injections
$k[X]/I\to \prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_{i}$ and $k[Y]/J\to
\prod_jk[Y]/\mathfrak{q}_j$. Therefore, we have an injection $k[X]/I\otimes_k k[Y]/J\to
(\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i)\otimes (\prod_jk[Y]/\mathfrak{q}_j)\cong
\prod_{i,j}k[X,Y]/(\mathfrak{p}_i,\mathfrak{q}_j)$. Since
$\prod_{i,j}k[X,Y]/(\mathfrak{p}_i,\mathfrak{q}_j)$ is reduced,
$k[X,Y]/(I,J)=k[X]/I\otimes k[Y]/J$ is also reduced.

**Edit** For the injectivity of $k[X]/I\otimes_k k[Y]/J\to
(\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i)\otimes (\prod_jk[Y]/\mathfrak{q}_j)$:

(a) $k[X]/I\to \prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i$ is injective, tensoring $k[Y]/J$ gives that  $k[X]/I\otimes_kk[Y]/J\to (\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i)\otimes_kk[Y]/J$ is injective.

(b)$k[Y]/J\to \prod_jk[Y]/\mathfrak{q}_j$ is injective, tensoring $\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i$ gives 
$(\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i)\otimes_kk[Y]/J\to (\prod_ik[X]/\mathfrak{p}_i)\otimes (\prod_jk[Y]/\mathfrak{q}_j)$ is injective.

Then the composition of two injections is injective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Apparently my algebra background is a lot weaker than I thought it was.  I am unsure about a few of the steps.  Is it true that tensoring two injective maps (over a field) preserves injectivity?  By reduced do you mean has no nilpotents?  (I'm not sure why)  Also I don't understand k[X,Y]/(I,J)=k[X]/I⊗k[Y]/J or (∏ik[X]/pi)⊗(∏jk[Y]/qj)≅∏i,jk[X,Y]/(pi,qj) (these look like two different cases of some general property I probably don't know  about.  (sorry for asking so many questions!!)

Comment: Ok I think tensoring over field preserves injectives because vector spaces are always flat modules.

Comment: You need to show $k[X]\otimes_k k[Y]=k[X,Y]$, and use the fact
$A/I\otimes_AM\cong M/IM$ for any ring $A$, an $A$-module $M$, an ideal
$I$ of $A$, then you can conclude that 
$k[X]/I\otimes_kk[Y]/J=(k[X]/I\otimes_{k[X]}(k[X]\otimes_kk[Y]))\otimes_{k[Y]}k[Y]/J=k[X,Y]/Ik[X,Y]\otimes_{k[Y]}k[Y]/J=k[X,Y]/(I,J)$. Clearly,
those isomorphisms are isomorphisms as modules, but they are  also
$k$-algebra homomorphisms, so, they are isomorphisms as rings.



We have an isomorphism $(A\times B)\otimes C\cong (A\otimes C)\times
(B\otimes C)$ as modules, then check the isomorphism is indeed a ring map.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hate to bother you again, but why are is ∏i,jk[X,Y]/(pi,qj) reduced?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Tensoring over a field preserves injectives, vector spaces are free. And, a ring is said reduced if it has no nilpotents. @Seth

Comment: Since all $k[X,Y]/(\mathfrak{p}_i,\mathfrak{q}_j)$ are domains by the first sentense of the answer. You are welcome.

Comment: k[X,Y] is an integral domain but why is ∏i,jk[X,Y]/(pi,qj) reduced?

Comment: @user26857 I believe it does follow from flatness since both sides are flat modules and if $N$ is flat then basically $f\otimes 1$ is injective if $f$ is.  (so do this twice on left argument and right argument) (ok this notation makes no sense but I think you see what I'm saying, I'm referencing a theorem from atiyah macdonald)

Comment: @user26857 yes, thank you.  That argument would be simpler (although I need to find a proof of that result somewhere then)

Comment: Although proving the tensor product of two domains is a domain is something we actually proved in class (using algebraic geometry)

Comment: @user26857 Thanks, I will go look up the theorem.  Somehow I feel like what I am trying to prove is almost equivalent to the tensor product of two reduced algebras is reduced, for a certain subclass of algebras.

Comment: @user26857 I read the proof, it was very nice.  I wish we were using these notes instead of Shafarevich.  Milne seems much more to my taste.

Comment: Ok I thought about this some more and over an algebraically closed field tensor product of two reduced algebras is a reduced algebra is basically the same as the product of varieties is a variety.  Tensor product of two domains is a domain is basically the same as product of two irreducible varieties is an irreducible variety.  I'm still confused about the proof of the result I'm looking for.  I will continue to think about it.

Comment: @user26857, I read the proof of Milne's, it is great, thanks.

Comment: @user119882 I just realized I was misinterpretting your notation the whole time and now I almost understand what you are saying... (lol)

Comment: @user26857 If you'd like to that would be great (but totally up to you).  I just posted a basic proof which solves the problem for me.  Proposition 2.19 in Atiyah Macdonald says: If an $A$-module $N$ is flat then given $f:M'\to M$ injective which $M$, $M'$ finitely generated then $f\otimes 1:M'\otimes N \to M \otimes N$ is injective.  The symmetric proposition must also be true so we compose the two injective maps.  In your example I think the ring hom an embedding to a subring without zero divisors.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer:

Since $I=(f_1,\dots, f_n)$ and $J=(g_1,\dots,g_m)$ are radical ideals, then $k[X]/I$ and $k[Y]/J$ are reduced $k$-algebras. If we assume that $k$ is a perfect field (in particular, algebraically closed) we get that $k[X]/I\otimes_kk[Y]/J=k[X,Y]/(I,J)$ is also reduced (see the last part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308411/121097) for perfect fields or Milne's book [*Algebraic Geometry*](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf), Proposition 4.15(a) for algebraically closed fields), and thus in this case the answer to the question is positive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just realized that I still don't understand k[X]/I⊗kk[Y]/J=k[X,Y]/(I,J).  I just went to write it down on paper and realized I can't justify all the steps.

Comment: @Seth Try to take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123543/why-does-a-i-otimes-r-b-j-conga-otimes-r-b-i-otimes-r-11-otimes-r-j).