# Prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f_i\in\mathbb{C}[X_i]$ be a monic polynomial of $X_i$, and we consider :
$$
I=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n) \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]
$$
the ideal formed by $f_i$. I think that $I$ will be maximal iff each $f_i$ is of degree $1$, but when this ideal will be prime and when it will be trivial ?

Comment: Your intuition works well when you have a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field like $\mathbf{C}$. Over the real numbers, for example when $n = 1$, the ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree 2 is maximal.

Comment: yes you are right i will fix it

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]/(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)\simeq\mathbb C[X_1]/(f_1)\otimes_{\mathbb C}\cdots\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[X_n]/(f_n)$. Now you can refer to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/301104/121097) in order to find out when your quotient is an integral domain. You can also use this isomorphism for finding the answer to the other questions.

Comment: can I get the answer more directly please, because i have any formation on this level of commutative algebra or in algebraic geometry.

Comment: I think a lot of people (aside from @user26857) are missing the part where you say that $f_i$ depends on $X_i$ only and not the other $X_j$.

Answer (score 2):

Over $\mathbf{C}$ or any other algebraically closed feel $K$, you proceed as follows. Suppose $I$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x_1,\dots , x_n]$. Then $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ is a field finitely generated as an algebra over $K$. By Zariski's lemma, it is a finite (hence algebraic) extension of $K$.

The hypothesis $K$ algebraically closed now implies that $K[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ is itself the copy of $K$ in this quotient. Therefore, if the class of $x_i$ in the quotient equals the class of $\alpha_i \in K$, then $x_i - \alpha_i$ must be in the ideal $I$.

Since the ideal $(x_1 - \alpha_1,\dots , x_n - \alpha_n)$ is maximal, you conclude that $I = (x_1 - \alpha_1,\dots , x_n - \alpha_n)$.

(Can you see what goes wrong when $K$ is not algebraically closed?)

(And I recommend that you use the case $n = 2$ as an exercise to investigate what prime but not maximal ideals of $\mathbf{C}[x, y]$ look like)